# Mutiny valuation in Halt & Catch Fire

Tags: halt-and-catch-fire

In the latest episode, S3E8, Mutiny is valued at

> $8 (or cents, it's not clear to me) a share, before falling to 6.00, then 5.00. This was lower than they had expected.

but what was the valuation they were expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a comment earlier in the episode

> "They say it's gonna open at fifteen [presumably $15 per share].

So just starting at just over half of expectations and ending up at 1/3 would be quite a shock.